# postfix stops to receive or send mails once weekly. Restart Server always fix it

Tags: postfix

i have an issue i can't deal with, that my mail server always stops about once weekly. i have every time to restart my server then every thing works fine.

in the log i can find the following error:

```
NOQUEUE: client=a68-116.smtp-out.amazonses.com[54.240.68.116]
Feb 14 12:29:26 mail postfix/smtpd[23528]: warning: connect to proxy filter inet:[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused
Feb 14 12:29:26 mail postfix/smtpd[23528]: proxy-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE: 451 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error; from=<010001864fafb540-11d9e933-3c9f-4424-9d25-fe891877e64d-000000@mail.canva.com> to=<MyMailAdress@myserver.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<a68-116.smtp-out.amazonses.com>
Feb 14 12:29:45 mail postfix/cleanup[17629]: E9F8B246724: message-id=<20230214112945.E9F8B246724@mail.myserver.de>
Feb 14 12:29:45 mail postfix/qmgr[26618]: E9F8B246724: from=<double-bounce@mail.myserver.de>, size=1532, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

knowing that i have increased the size_limit in the main config.

one of the post was saying i have to check if amavis is running.
However, It seems like more than one service installed on my ubuntu server named amavis:

```
root@mail:/var# systemctl status amavis
amavisd-new.service            amavisd-snmp-subagent.service  amavis-mc.service              amavis.service                 amavis-snmp-subagent.service
```

i can see that all of them is inactive after i restarted my server.

also i have a mail in my root that shows up in my server. It has the following message:

```
Received: by mail.myserver.de (Postfix, from userid 0)
id 5472D246727; Tue, 14 Feb 2023 15:54:05 +0100 (CET)
From: root@mail.myserver.de (Cron Daemon)
To: root@mail.myserver.de
Subject: Cron <root@mail>    $PYTHON $INSTANCE/manage.py generate_rights
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <PYTHON=/srv/modoboa/env/bin/python>
X-Cron-Env: <INSTANCE=/srv/modoboa/instance>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20230214145405.5472D246727@mail.myserver.de>
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 15:54:05 +0100 (CET)

/srv/modoboa/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/utils.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
  import cryptography  # noqa
/srv/modoboa/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:104: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (5.0.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.12) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

I would be glad for any help!
Thank you!

Comment: It looks like amavis fails, the incoming queue is unable to be emptied (because the service where it is supposed to go failed), and fills up. Problem is not with Postfix; fix your amavis or whatever sits on the port 10024. (And for help, post relevant logs: from the service manager and the service.) Also, think of implementing before-queue mail filtering; more messages will be rejected earlier and queues will fill slower. The earlier you reject spam, the better for you.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you for your reply. Do you know where is it logging? The amavis i mean. I need to know why it always fails.

Comment: I never used it since 2012. Try searching in /var/log/amavis or /var/log/amavisd. Try to read a config file for a logging configuration.